# Scrapy x path: only get first item in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get the details of every element of this page: https://www.mrlodge.de/wohnungen/

I did this quite often with a for loop. However this time it only returns the first element. There has to be a problem in the loop because when I am using getall() instead of get(), I get all the details I need but not ordered.

Please help

```
import scrapy

class MrlodgeSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mrlodge_spider'

    payload = '''
        {mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bdate_from%5D=&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brent_from%5D=1000&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brent_to%5D=8500&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bpersons%5D=1&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bkids%5D=0&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brooms_from%5D=1&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brooms_to%5D=9&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Barea_from%5D=20&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Barea_to%5D=480&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bsterm%5D=&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bradius%5D=50&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bmvv%5D=&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bobjecttype_cb%5D%5B%5D=w&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bobjecttype_cb%5D%5B%5D=h&mrl_ft%5Bpage%5D=1}
    '''
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.mrlodge.de/wohnungen/', method='POST',
                    body = self.payload, headers={"content-type": "application/json"})

    def parse(self, response):
        for apartment in response.xpath("//div[@class='mrl-ft-results mrlobject-list']"):
            yield {
                'info': apartment.xpath(".//div[@class='obj-smallinfo']/text()").get()
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
//div[contains(@class,'mrlobject-row')]
```

instead of

```
//div[@class='mrl-ft-results mrlobject-list']
```

to get the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the first xpath query

```
class MrlodgeSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mrlodge_spider'

    payload = '''
    {mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bdate_from%5D=&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brent_from%5D=1000&mrl
    _ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brent_to%5D=8500&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bpersons%5D=1&mrl_ft%5Bfd
    %5D%5Bkids%5D=0&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brooms_from%5D=1&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Brooms
    _to%5D=9&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Barea_from%5D=20&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Barea_to%5D=4
    80&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bsterm%5D=&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bradius%5D=50&mrl_ft%5Bfd
    %5D%5Bmvv%5D=&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%5Bobjecttype_cb%5D%5B%5D=w&mrl_ft%5Bfd%5D%
    5Bobjecttype_cb%5D%5B%5D=h&mrl_ft%5Bpage%5D=1}
'''

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://www.mrlodge.de/wohnungen/',
            method='POST',
            body=self.payload,
            headers={"content-type": "application/json"},
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        for apartment in response.xpath('//div[@class="mrlobject-list__item mrlobject-row"]'):
            yield {
                'info': apartment.xpath(".//div[@class='obj-smallinfo']/text()").get()
            }
```

Comment: thanks, you are a life saver the dot .// is my problem clue